# How can I delete the jumplist cache?

Tags: windows-8.1, jumplist

I recently used PC Tools Registry Mechanic on my computer to clear recent history, and whenever you use the program to clear your history, it removes your jumplists until the program in question is opened to regenerate them.

In the past, this has worked fine, but the last time I ran the program, the jumplists didn't come back for some of the programs. I am guessing that my jumplist cache is corrupt, but I don't know for sure.

I would like to delete the cache if it exists. How can I do this?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stop using tools that "optimized" your registry.  You really are doing more harm then good.

Comment: @Ramhound So I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to disable then enabled this functionality.

Navigate to: **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items** and Select **Taskbar and Navigation**

[image]

Disable and Enable both privacy options.

[image]

Comment: I am not trying to clear just data, I am trying to delete all jumplist info, and by that I mean remove the jumplists all together and allow the programs themselves to regenerate them. The programs are not regenerating them as they should be.

Comment: @DavidB - This will do exactly that.  You have in the past simply forced deleted the files.  This will disable them, once you enable the feature again, the files should be able to be generated again.  You can always try some other program that does clears the jumplist also.